# invalid syntax in rules file in pyke

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyke

I'm totally new to Pyke and I'm trying to run a simple code but it gives me a `syntax error`.
I installed pyke3 from source code from sourceforge.com and I use python 3.10, python 3.97 and both give the same error.
Here is the code of all the files:

**1- driver.py**

```
from pyke import knowledge_engine

engine = knowledge_engine.engine(__file__)


def rules():

    engine.reset()

    engine.activate('rules.krb')
```

**2- facts.kfb**

```
has_age_of("some name", 38)
was_born_in("some name", 1976)
has_number_of_file("some name", 470)
has_gravidity_of("some name", Gs)
has_parity_of("some name", "p9 + 0")
has_gestational_age_of("some name", "10 weeks + 3 days")
works_as("some name", "some occupation")
has_blood_group("some name", "A+ve")
```

**3-rules.krb**

```
# KRB.krb

the_age
    use aged_with($age, $name)
    when
    facts.has_age_of($name, $age)
```

and where I run the driver this happens:

```
writing [compiled_krb]/facts.fbc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\work\hospital_project\project\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    engine = knowledge_engine.engine(__file__)
  File "C:\Users\serag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyke\knowledge_engine.py", line 113, in __init__
    target_package.compile(self)
  File "C:\Users\serag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyke\target_pkg.py", line 285, in compile
    self.do_by_ext('compile',
  File "C:\Users\serag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyke\target_pkg.py", line 265, in do_by_ext
    return getattr(self, "%s_%s" % (prefix, ext))(filename, *args)
  File "C:\Users\serag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyke\target_pkg.py", line 298, in compile_krb
    return krb_compiler.compile_krb(rb_name, self.package_name,
  File "C:\Users\serag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyke\krb_compiler\__init__.py", line 114, in compile_krb
    ast = krbparser.parse(krbparser, filename)
  File "C:\Users\serag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyke\krb_compiler\krbparser.py", line 601, in parse
    return parser.parse(f.read() + '\n', lexer=scanner.lexer, tracking=True,
  File "C:\Users\serag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyke\krb_compiler\ply\yacc.py", line 263, in parse
    return self.parseopt(input,lexer,debug,tracking,tokenfunc)
  File "C:\Users\serag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyke\krb_compiler\ply\yacc.py", line 792, in parseopt
    tok = self.errorfunc(errtoken)
  File "C:\Users\serag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyke\krb_compiler\krbparser.py", line 553, in p_error
    raise SyntaxError("invalid syntax",
  File "e:\work\hospital_project\project\rules.krb", line 6
    facts.has_age_of($name, $age)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help.